# Bash array with dynamic name

Tags: bash

I made the following code :

```
tableList=("books" "centres" "contacts" "courses")

for tbName in ${tableList[@]}; do
        declare -a tableName="ar_${tbName}"
        for col in $(mysql --login-path=local $db -Bse "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PEG' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tbName'"); do
                eval tableName+=("$col")
        done
done

set
```

And I have a DB like this :

```
desc books
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| book1  | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book2  | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| book3  | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc contacts
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| contact1 | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact2 | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact3 | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The purpose was to get columns name for each table described in array tableList and put them in an array with ar_+[table name] as array name.

For instance all columns name from table books should should have been put in an array called
ar_books.

like this :

```
ar_books = ("book1" "book2" "book3)
```

Unfortunately this does not work, and the set show that the new array name (ar_courses for instance) is put in an array called tableName as first occurence but no array called ar_courses had been created.

I looked over stackexchange since yesterday afternoon and I don't see how to make this works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not designed to work well with multi dimensional array. Maybe you should evaluate rewriting to a different language like python.

However you can use this as a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151190/290087

Comment: Hi,They are not multidimensional arrays. May be my explanation was not clear enough, I slightly modified it to make it clearer. My issue is not putting the data I need in the arrays. that's ok. It's just to set the array name as ar_['table_name'] (table name got from array tableList)